# Spring data not returning unique entities for multiple, unique rows

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

So the backstory of this problem: I have created an event calendar that allows events to span multiple days. In my DB i have a table for the event and i have a table called event_dates, which is just event_id and date.

To retrieve the rows correctly with the event dates i do an `INNER JOIN on EVENT_DATES (event_id)`

The return from the db is correct, the row contains all of the information about the event along with the 'date' column tacked on at the end.

My domain for Event class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="events")
@SecondaryTable(name = "event_date", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="event_id"))
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="event_id")
    private Long id;

    private String eventTitle;
    private String eventCategory;
    private String eventType;


    @Column(table="event_date", name="date", columnDefinition = "DATE", unique=true)
    private LocalDate date;

    @Column(table="event_date", name="event_date_id")
    private Long eventDateId;

    private boolean allDayEvent;

    @Column(name = "start_time", columnDefinition = "TIME")
    private LocalTime startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time", columnDefinition = "TIME")
    private LocalTime endTime;

    private String timezone;
    private boolean onlineEvent;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    private String language;
    private String description;
    private boolean register;
    private String registrationLink;
    private boolean multiDay;

}
```

Here is where the issue occurs:

While the db is returning every row along with the correct dates (no duplicate days),

spring data is creating the first row as an entity with the first date, but then when it hits the next row it sees that the ID for the event is the same as the previous entity and it just copies that entity over again in the array, it never checks to see if the date is unique for that entity. The dates never change and it's important that it does or my api returns  events happening over and over again on the same day (correct amount of duplicates however haha).

So the return value from spring is the correct number of entries but the dates for each entity remain the same because it's not checking that the event_id and date fields are unique to each entity being added to the array of return results.

Ive seen using `@UniqueConstraint` but the problem is that the `@UniqueConstraint`s span two tables, not the same table, and I haven't found any examples that show how to configure for this type of situation.

I'm like 95% there I just need the dates for each entity to be unique!

Comment: Show the code for `Event` in full.

Comment: updated to include full Event

Comment: This makes zero sense. It looks to me like you have an Event and and an Event has a collection of dates. You need to read up on JPA  relationships.

Comment: the client wants a list of days to iterate over. not a list of events with multiple dates in a collection. that's why i must do it this way.

Comment: Either Event has a *collection* of dates or Event has a JPA composite key consisting the id plus the date. You need to  look at the basics.

Comment: ahh yep, so i can just create a composite key. this makes sense.

Comment: @AddisonJoseph composite keys are not a good practise, and shouId be avoided. I suggest you to take a look on autoincremental IDs or autogenerated technical IDs.